# Scroll content inside @gorhom/bottom-sheet - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet, react-native-scrollview

I am trying to implement a Comments Section inside a Bottom Sheet (@gorhom/bottom-sheet).
The problem I am facing is that when I try to scroll the content (comments), it doesn't work, and instead the bottom sheet collapses.

Here is what I tried :

```
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={0}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text>{comments} Comments</Text>
          <Comments />
        </View>
      </BottomSheet>
```

Comment: can you add code sample as well. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of View please use BottomSheetScrollView from @gorhom/bottom-sheet
or use ScrollView from react-native-gesture-handler.

```
<BottomSheet
    ref={bottomSheetRef}
    index={0}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    onChange={handleSheetChanges}
  >
    <BottomSheetScrollView style={styles.contentContainer}>
      <Text>{comments} Comments</Text>
      <Comments />
    </BottomSheetScrollView>
  </BottomSheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to make your `View` scrollable, you need to use a `ScrollView` component. However, it will be needed to import it from `'react-native-gesture-handler'` instead of the `'react-native'` one.

You can get more information in [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/1085).

Answer (score 0):

Use BottomSheetScrollView instead of BottomSheet

https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetscrollview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).